# How to put an image on layout page?

Tags: c#, html, css, razor

I have alittle project using html, css, c# with razor syntax.

I have layout page (on the sheard folder) and I use renderbody().

On the layout page I ave an image("intro.png") that I want to be on all pages (because that I put the image on the layout page), but when I go to other pages on my little website the page doesn't apeear, it's appear only on the first page.
here is asection of my layout page:

```
    <!-- Introduction --> 

    <header>
        <h2>head?</h2>
    </header>
    <p>some text.</p>
    <img src="Content/images/intro.png">
</section>
<div id="content">
    @RenderBody()
    <aside>
        <section>
            <header>
                <h3>Categories</h3>
            </header>

        </section>
        <section>
            <header>
                <h3>Archives</h3>
            </header>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">December 2008</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">January 2009</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">February 2009</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">March 2009</a></li>
            </ul>
        </section>
    </aside>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

instead of giving link to image this way:

```
 <img src="Content/images/intro.png">
```

Use this :

```
 <img src=@Url.Content("~/Content/images/intro.png")>
```

I think there is a problem with Image Path .. I think above answer will solve that problem..